# Regex for matching literal strings

Tags: regex, haskell, posix

I'm trying to write a regular expression which will match a string.  For simplicity, I'm only concerned with double quote (") strings for the moment.

So far I have this: `"\"[^\"]*\""`

This works for most strings but fails when there is an escaped double quote such as this:

```
"a string \" with an escaped quote"
```

In this case, it only matches up to the escaped quote.

I've tried several things to allow an escaped quote but so far I've been unsuccessful, can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: what kinds of things have you tried?

Comment: Please always specify the language or tool you intend to use. [Regex implementations vary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), and a solution that works in one language may not work in another.

Comment: The language is Haskell.  I'm using the Text.Regex.Posix library.

Comment: not sure if this is possible AT ALL without lookaround - which AFAIK is not supported by POSIX -- are there any other libraries or languages that can be used for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solve it myself:

```
"\"(\\.|[^\"\\])*\""
```

Comment: Very simple and elegant!!  But wait a second!! What if (teeny, tiny possibility of this happening) you want to use a quote character in the string but not INSIDE a quoted text block? I see no way of IGNORING that one, and it would falsely "start" a quoted text block... you COULD make them all double-double-quotes (`""`), which would match as an empty quotation and be discarded (or reverted to single quotes...) - that would take extra documentation: "use `\"` to represent a quote character INSIDE a quotation, but `""` to represent a quote character OUTSIDE a quotation"...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"[^"\\\r\n]*(?:\\.[^"\\\r\n]*)*"
```

If you want a multi-line escaped string you can use:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
```

Comment: Does POSIX (assuming ERE) support non-capturing groups (the `(?:` in your expressions)?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"((\\")|[^"(\\")])+"
```

From [Regular Expression Library](http://www.regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=124).

Answer (score 0):

You need a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Check if this works?

```
"\"[^\"]*(?<!\\)"
```

`(?<!\\)"` is supposed to match `"` that's **not** followed by `\`.

Comment: To escape a quote the `\\` is placed **before** the quote, not after.

Comment: "(?<!\\)" is supposed to match " that's not **followed** by \"

Comment: does POSIX even support lookbehind? or am I reading something wrong?

Comment: This is from the reference I quoted: "`(?<!a)b` matches a "b" that is not preceded by an "a", using negative lookbehind.".... I derived `(?<!\\)"` from that. **Look-around is not supported in POSIX B/ERE** according to http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to accept escaped anything.

`" [^"\\]* (?: \\. [^"\\]* )* "` would be the fastest.

`"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` compressed.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX does not, AFAIK, support lookaround - without it, there is really no way to do this with just regular expressions. However, according to a POSIX emulator I have (no access to a native environment or library), This might get you close, in certain cases:

```
"[^\"]*"|"[^\]*\\|\\[^\"]*[\"]
```

it will capture the part before and the part after the escaped quote... with this source string (ignore the line breaks, an imagine it's all in one string):

```
I want to match "this text" and "This text, where there is an escaped 
slash (\\), and an \"escaped quote\" (\")", but I also want to handle\\ escaped
back-slashes, as in "this text, with a \\ backslash: \\" -- with a little
text behind it!
```

it will capture these groups:

```
"this text"                                          -- simple, quoted string
"This text, where there is an escaped slash (\       -- part 1 of quoted string
\), and an \                                         -- part 2
"escaped quote\                                      -- part 3
" (\                                                 -- part 4
")"                                                  -- part 5, and ends with a quote
\\                                                   -- not part of a quoted string
"this text, with a \                                 -- part 1 of quoted string
\ backslash: \                                       -- part 2
\"                                                   -- part 3, and ends with a quote
```

With further analysis you can combine them, as appropriate:

- If the group starts and ends with a `"`, then it is fine on its own
- If the group starts with a `"`, and ends with a `\`, then it needs to be *IMMEDIATELY* followed by another match group that either ends with a quote character itself, or recursively continues to be IMMEDIATELY followed by another match group
- If the group does not immediately follow another match, it is not part of a quoted string

I think that's all the analysis that you need - but make sure to test it!!!

Let me know if this idea helps!

**EDIT:**
Additional note: just to be clear, for this to work all quotes in the entire source string must be escaped if they are not to be used as delimiters, and backslashes must be escaped everywhere as well